# Complex numbers such that $(z-4)^4=-1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Find all complex numbers $z$ in Cartesian form such that $(z-4)^4=-1$.

This is what I did: I squared root both side making $-1$ into $i$ and $(z-4)^2$ and I took square of both side again and had $i^2$ which is equal to $-1$ and the other side $(z-1)$. At the end I had $z=0$.

Comment: Hello: great job explaining your steps up until now. That is commendable! Another tip though: don't title your question anything like "please help with this." Inane and useless titles like that tend to turn people away from your question. In a case like this, simply putting the question you are solving into the title suffices.  Further tips are available in the FAQ section.

Comment: Hint: Think about roots of unity. All values of $z-4$ will be primitive eighth roots of unity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is what I did: I squared root both side making $-1$ into $i$ and $(z-4)^2$

This is on the right track. Except, when you square root both sides, you need to do $\pm$. So instead of getting $i$ you get $\pm i$:
$$
(z - 4)^2 = \pm i
$$

> and I took square of both side again and had $i^2$ which is equal to $-1$ and the other side $(z-1)$. At the end I had $z=0$.

The next step is to take the square root again (not squaring both sides), is that what you meant to do?
This part is a little tricky: when we take square root of both sides we need to know what are all the square roots of $i$ and $-i$.
The square roots of $i$ are
$$
\pm \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} i \right)
$$
and the square roots of $-i$ are
$$
\pm \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} i \right)
$$
So, when we take the square root of the equation $(z - 4)^2 = \pm i$, we get four possibilities (the two square roots of $i$, and the two square roots of $-i$):
\begin{align*}
z - 4 &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} i \\
z - 4 &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} i \\
z - 4 &= -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} i \\
z - 4 &= -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} i.
\end{align*}
Can you find the answer in all of the four cases?

Answer (score 1):

You'd better use the exponential form of $z-4=r\mathrm e^{i\theta}\enspace(r\ge 0)$. This yields the equation
$$(z-4)^4=r^4\mathrm e^{4i\theta}=-1=\mathrm e^{i\pi}\iff\begin{cases} r^4=1\\
4\theta\equiv \pi\bmod 2\pi
\end{cases}\iff\begin{cases} r=1\\
\theta\equiv \frac\pi4\bmod \frac\pi2
\end{cases}$$
Can you end the computations?

Comment: Please I’m kind of new to complex numbers wish you could break it down a little

Comment: @Bernard I think you meant $(z - 4)^4$. Also note that the question asks to put it in cartesian form.

Comment: I just used that $r_1\mathrm e^{i\theta_1}=r_2\mathrm e^{i\theta_2}$ if and only if the module is the same ($r_1=r_2$) and the argument is also the same (the argument is defined modulo 2π): ·$\theta_1\equiv\theta_2\pmod{2\pi}$. What's not clear?

Comment: @6005: You're right. I'll fix it instantly. Thanks for pointing the typo! I had seen  cartesian coordinates are required, but I left the final steps to the O.P.

Answer (score 0):

Write the equation as $(z-4)^4=-1 = e^{i\pi+i2\pi k}$ with integer $k$. There are four solutions, given by,

$$z-4 = e^{\frac14 (i\pi+i2\pi k) },\>\>\>\>\>k=0,1,2,3$$

Thus, in Cartesian form, the four solutions are,

$$z = 4 + \cos\left[\frac\pi4(1+2k)\right]+i\sin\left[\frac\pi4(1+2k)\right] $$

with $k=0,1,2$ and $3$